# How do I filter lines using grep which have a specific character as the 35 character?

Tags: unix, grep

So I am trying to monitor a screen session which automatically copies all its lines to a log file. I am currently doing this using:

```
tail -f logs/latest.log
```

But what I really wanted to do with this is to not see all the lines that don't have @ as the 35 character.
I have tried looking everywhere, but so far I don't have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
tail -f logs/latest.log | grep --line-buffered "^.\{34\}@"
```

which looks for lines containing any 34 characters followed by an `@`.

Or, something like this with `sed`:

```
tail -f ... | sed -nl '/^.\{34\}@/p'
```

Comment: The first time I used it it worked, but then it stopped working.

Comment: Maybe there were no matching lines the second time.

Comment: I just tested that and it appears to be the case. Thx for the help!